# When post a question the side bar's position is not fixed while scrolling the page

Tags: bug, status-completed, design, sidebar

When post a question ("Ask Question") the side bar's position is not fixed while scrolling the page. There are some extra spaces are displaying in the top.

GIF for the same:

[image: Side bar not fixed when scroll the page]

**Update:** This issue occurs in the [Markdown help](https://meta.stackexchange.com/editing-help) page too when scrolling the page.

Comment: Repro on Chrome/Win7